# Angular universal 'npm run prerender' command never stops

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using Angular universal with Angular 9 and Angular Fire 6.

I managed to prerender my application with `npm run prerender` without any errors.
My routes get pre rendered and the `index.html` files looks fine.

Except the command itself, it never finishes.
The last lines i get:

```
...
Prerendering 4 route(s) to {{projekt URL}}\browser
CREATE {{projekt URL}}\browser\index.html (66857 bytes)
CREATE {{projekt URL}}\browser\home\index.html (66857 bytes)
CREATE {{projekt URL}}\browser\edit\index.html (66857 bytes)
CREATE {{projekt URL}}\browser\login\index.html (66857 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found out, that somehow the forked process(es) did not terminate correctly. I didn't know how to help but use a small workaround, which I'll execute as NPM script before the actual prerendering:

```
"prerender:fix-exit": "sed -i -e \"s/}))().then().catch();/}))().then(()=>process.exit(0)).catch(()=>process.exit(1));/g\" ./node_modules/@nguniversal/builders/src/prerender/render.js",
```

It will basically call `process.exit(0)` in case of success, or `process.exit(1)` in case of error. In theory, this should also work with a builder configuration of `numProcesses` > 1.

Comment: Also be sure that you care about `setInterval`-like things.